# How to use `let` keyword and select ValueTuple in the same LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-7.0

Ideally I would want to define some temporary variables with `let` keyword to not repeat the same `Contains` method call, calculate some other stuff with those values and then return `ValueTuple`. Is that possible in one chained or query expression? So far I've managed it only with 2 expressions. Oh, the collection is `IEnumerable`, of course.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace FeaturesTest
{
  class Program
  {
    class Song
    {
      public string Artist { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class User
    {
      public List<Song> FavouriteSongs { get; set; }
      public List<Song> HatedSongs { get; set; }
    }
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
      List<Song> allSongs = new List<Song>
      {
        new Song{ Artist = "Atheist", Name = "Enthralled in Essence" },
        new Song{ Artist = "Death", Name = "Jealosy" },
        new Song{ Artist = "Cynic", Name = "Evolutionary Sleeper" },
        new Song{ Artist = "Ghost", Name = "Square Hammer" },
      };

      User bob = new User
      {
        FavouriteSongs = new List<Song>
        {
          allSongs[0],
          allSongs[1]
        },
        HatedSongs = new List<Song>
        {
          allSongs[3],
        }
      };

      var objects = from song in allSongs
                    let isFavourite = bob.FavouriteSongs.Contains( song )
                    let isHated = bob.HatedSongs.Contains( song )
                    select new
                    {
                      Artist = song.Artist,
                      Name = song.Name,
                      IsFavourite = isFavourite,
                      IsHated = isHated,
                      IsNeutral = !isFavourite && !isHated
                    };
      var tuples = objects.Select( o => (Artist: o.Artist,
                                         Name: o.Name,
                                         IsFavourite: o.IsFavourite,
                                         IsHated: o.IsHated,
                                         IsNeutral: o.IsNeutral) );

      Console.WriteLine( "Artist     Name                      Is Favourite    Is Hated   Is Neutral" );
      Console.WriteLine( "------     ----                      ------------    --------   ----------" );
      foreach( (string Artist, string Name, bool IsFavourite, bool IsHated, bool IsNeutral) in tuples )
      {
        Console.WriteLine( $"{Artist,-10} {Name,-25} {IsFavourite,-15} {IsHated,-10} {IsNeutral}" );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something: Yes - just project a NamedTuple instead of an Anonymous Object:

```
var objects = from song in allSongs
              let isFavourite = bob.FavouriteSongs.Contains( song )
              let isHated = bob.HatedSongs.Contains( song )
              select (
                  song.Artist,
                  song.Name,
                  isFavourite,
                  isHated,
                  IsNeutral : !isFavourite && !isHated
              );
```

In addition as for your `foreach` loop - you already gave the names, just use `var` (I think it is easier to read):

```
foreach( var t in tuples )
{
    Console.WriteLine( $"{t.Artist,-10} {t.Name,-25} {t.IsFavourite,-15} {t.IsHated,-10} {t.IsNeutral}" );
}
```

Also your `Contains` is brittle. It will compare the objects by there references and not the content. In this current example it is ok but if the objects were different instances with the same content it wouldn't have worked. To correct that implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

Comment: Damn, that was obvious! Still not quite used to that syntax :) Also good point about `Contains`, didn't think of it first.

Comment: @JerrySmith - glad it helped :)